# Circular transformation of a line.

Tags: geometry, transformation

I've just started to learn transformations in complex plane and i'd like to understand how to proof, that an image of a line not-going through the center of inversion is a circle going through the center of inversion. If  equation of my line is $z(\frac {a} {2} + \frac {b} {2i} )+\bar {z}( \frac {a} {2}-\frac {b} {2i} ) + c = 0$. I also read that i have to apply the transformation $\frac {1}{z}$, but i dont understand from where it comes. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think there are several similar questions here, for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258148/finding-the-image-of-this-line-under-1-z

Comment: Yes, but i dont really understand from where come that $\frac {1}{z}$

Comment: Well, I don't know the context of your particular problem, but I think historically someone just thought "Hmm, I wonder what happens if I take a line in the complex plane and apply $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ to that line?" - and then they saw that it turns into a circle or another line. And after that, the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ has just remained in the complex analysis curriculum. I dunno.